# Make nginx execute a specific PHP file when loading an exact location

Tags: linux, nginx, http

I've just implemented the `Autodiscover` feature for `MS Outlook Clients` through `Nginx` and a `PHP` script. While the setup is working like a charm I would like to do a little improvement on the nginx server block but I'm not succeeding.

The current nginx server block looks like the following one, and as you can see when location `/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` is loaded clients get redirected to `/autodiscover/autodiscover.php` and then nginx executes the PHP script and returns the result to the client.

```
        location = /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
        {
            rewrite .* /autodiscover/autodiscover.php redirect;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass          php-fpm73;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
          include               /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param         SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param         HTTPS              on;
       }
```

I would like to modify the nginx server block so when `/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` is requested the `/autodiscover/autodiscover.php` PHP script is executed and then the result is returned to the client without redirecting so the client's URL stays the same, `/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
rewrite .* /autodiscover/autodiscover.php last;
```

instead. The `last` flag would force nginx to break current location processing and seach for the new one according to the rewrited URI.

You can check complete `rewrite` directive syntax [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

Comment: Thank u so much! :)